# The while loop sometimes is infinite

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Copy_Worksheets_Columns_Rows_to_ALL_D2()
    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
    'Task: Copy worksheets, columns and rows to ALL (D2)
    
    Dim sourceSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet3 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
    Dim sourceRow As Range, targetRow As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim ALL_File As String
    Dim ALL_Extension As String
    
    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
    myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then myPath = myPath + "\"
            
    SampleFileExtension = "sample.xlsx"
        
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(myPath & SampleFileExtension, Local:=True)
    
    'Worksheet in source workbook to be copied as a new sheet
    Set sourceSheet1 = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set sourceSheet2 = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set sourceSheet3 = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    
    Set sourceColumn = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("T:AD")
    Set sourceRow = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("1026:1038")
    
    fnd = "[" & sourceWorkbook.Name & "]"
    rplc = ""
        
    'ALL Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    ALL_Extension = "*.2.*.ALL.xlsx"
    'ALL Target Path with Ending Extention
    ALL_File = Dir(myPath & ALL_Extension)
    
    Do While ALL_File <> ""
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & ALL_File, Local:=True)
       
       'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
        
        sourceSheet3.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        sourceSheet2.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        sourceSheet1.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set targetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("T:AD")
        sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
        Set targetRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("1026:1038")
        sourceRow.Copy Destination:=targetRow
                
       'Perform the Find/Replace All
        Sheets(4).Range("A1:AD1038").Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        Exit Do
        
       'Get next matching file
        ALL_File = Dir()
            
    Loop
        
    sourceWorkbook.Close False
    
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
      'MsgBox "Copy D2 worksheets, columns and rows to ALL (Task 5) Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do, what the expected outcome is. Also show what you have done to debug the program. Did you step through the code inspecting variables? Show your efforts.

Comment: @trincot the code is suppose to loop through 100 files, making some edits to them and saving them again. I'm unable to debug it, previously I didn't write Exit do, but now I'm including that. Yes I've done step through. To be honest the problem with this code is that sometimes it does loop properly and sometimes it becomes infinite, so I'm clueless

Comment: So what is the code supposed to do? Surely, you can do better than *"making some edits"*.

Comment: Are you sure it is infinite? Is it possible there are a large number of files and it is slow to process?

Comment: @VBasic2008 look at the comment at the top of the sub. It's pretty clear what the overall goal is.

Comment: @VBasic2008 what can I do, I really haven't coded using VB, c++ and python is my expertise

Comment: @siride i mean the code is acting weird. Sometimes it loops porpoerly, sometimes infinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify files in a loop that is based on `Dir` you may get into this situation. `Dir` is great when you don't modify the files in the folder you are iterating over, but if you do make modifications, it is risky.

A pragmatic solution is to first collect the files you want to process, and then loop over that collection:

```
Dim ALL_File As Variant  ' Make sure it is Variant now
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection

' Other initialisations ...
' ...
' ...

ALL_File = Dir(myPath & ALL_Extension)

' Collect file names  
Do While ALL_File <> ""
    c.Add ALL_File
    ALL_File = Dir
Loop

' Iterate over the collection of file names
For Each ALL_File In c
    Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & ALL_File, Local:=True)
       
    ' ... process the open workbook ...
    ' ...

    destinationWorkbook.Close True
Next
```

In summary:

- Modify the declaration of `ALL_File` so it is a `Variant`, not a `String`
- Add the declaration of `c` and its initialisation.
- Add the new, smaller loop that uses `Dir` to populate the `c` collection.
- Turn your existing loop from a `Do While...Loop` into a `For Each...Next` loop (as shown above)
- Remove the last statement from that loop, which did the call to `Dir`

Comment: should i add this to another module or rectify my current module using this?

Comment: You should edit your existing code so it aligns with this.